# How do I use a custom twig template with a render element?

Tags: theming

I am fairly new to Drupal 8 module development, so I decided to follow a tutorial at https://docs.acquia.com/articles/drupal-8-creating-elements-theming-elements-and-managing-frontend-libraries, which describes the process of setting up a module with a render element using a twig template. I followed the code exactly and have included the sections I'm working on below (I did not include the info and routing code).

I am seeing my controller return the correct elements, however I am unable to see the twig template render with additional markup. From what I understand the element 'my_element' should be getting returned from the controller's second element in the render array ... 'type'=>'my_element'. Also my_element is defined in hook_theme in the module file but I think I am getting confused on how this links to the template called my-element.html.twig. Can anyone provide any tips or suggestions?

theme_example.module

```
<?php

/**
* Implements hook_theme().
*/
function theme_example_theme() {
  $items = [
    'my_element' => [
      'render element' => 'element',
    ],
  ];
  return $items;
}
```

src/Controller/ThemeExampleController.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\theme_example\Controller\ThemeExampleController.
 */

namespace Drupal\theme_example\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * Controller routines for theme example routes.
 */
class ThemeExampleController extends ControllerBase {

  public function simple() {
    return [
      'example one' => [
        '#markup' => '<div>Markup Example</div>',
      ],
      'example two' => [
        '#type' => 'my_element',
        '#label' => $this->t('Example Label'),
        '#description' => $this->t('This is the description text.'),
      ],
    ];
  }
}
```

src/Element/MyElement.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\theme_example\Element\MyElement.
 */

namespace Drupal\theme_example\Element;

use Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderElement;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Provides an example element.
 *
 * @RenderElement("my_element")
 */
class MyElement extends RenderElement {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getInfo() {
    $class = get_class($this);
    return [
      '#theme' => 'my_element',
      '#label' => 'Default Label',
      '#description' => 'Default Description',
      '#pre_render' => [
        [$class, 'preRenderMyElement'],
      ],
    ];
  }

  /**
   * Prepare the render array for the template.
   */
  public static function preRenderMyElement($element) {
    // Create a link render array using our #label.
    $element['link'] = [
      '#type' => 'link',
      '#title' => $element['#label'],
      '#url' => Url::fromUri('http://www.drupal.org'),
    ];

    // Create a description render array using #description.
    $element['description'] = [
      '#markup' => $element['#description']
    ];

    $element['pre_render_addition'] = [
      '#markup' => 'Additional text.'
    ];

    // Create a variable.
    $element['#random_number'] = rand(0,100);

    return $element;
  }
}
```

templates/my-element.html.twig

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to my_element.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - element: Element that will be rendered.
 * - element['link'] : a link
 * - element['description'] : a description
 * - element['pre_render_addition'] : added during the #pre_render function
 * - element['random_number'] : a random number variable, won't be printed with the element.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}

<div class="myElement">
  <div class="randomNumber">Random Number: {{ element['#random_number'] }}</div>
  <p>{{ element.description }}</p>
  {{ element.link }}
</div>

{# Debug output #}
<div>
  <h3>We print the element</h3>
  {{ element }}
  <h3>Link</h3>
  {{ element.link }}
  <h3>Description</h3>
  {{ element.description }}
  <h3>#pre_render addition</h3>
  {{ element.pre_render_addition }}
  <h3>Random number (not printed when we printed the whole element</h3>
  {{ element['#random_number'] }}
</div>
```

Comment: Not seeing any issues in your code, have you tried to rebuild cache?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. Explaining the flow below:

The key for item in the array is what you will need to call the template And the key is : my_element

```
<?php

/**
* Implements hook_theme().
*/
function theme_example_theme() {
  $items = [
   'my_element' => [
   'render element' => 'element',
    ],
  ];
  return $items;
 }
```

Then creating twig template and replacing underscores with dashes like this : my-element.html.twig under templates folder.
By render element which is 'element' ,calling each field.
After creating both the file , where you are returning your render array make a call to your twig template. which is below:

```
class MyElement extends RenderElement {
/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function getInfo() {
  $class = get_class($this);
   return [
    '#theme' => 'my_element',
    '#label' => 'Default Label',
    '#description' => 'Default Description',
    '#pre_render' => [
       [$class, 'preRenderMyElement'],
     ],
   ];
 }
```

Then using the key my_element in controller for fetching all from preRenderMyElement().

```
 public function simple() {
   return [
     'example one' => [
     '#markup' => '<div>Markup Example</div>',
     ],
     'example two' => [
     '#type' => 'my_element',
     '#label' => $this->t('Example Label'),
     '#description' => $this->t('This is the 
      description 
      text.'),
      ],
    ];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

All your code works.

I created your module, adding a routes and info file to make it work, enabled it, visited `/theme-example` and I could see you template was being used.

See https://github.com/dahousecat/theme-example for the whole module.